# Best way to remove event specific event handlers in jQuery

Tags: jquery

So, here is the situation.  I have several objects of the same type that are all listening to the same event.  The handlers of each of these objects manipulate some part of the DOM.  These objects can be recreated or destroyed at almost any time, when they are destroyed they take the part of the DOM they are responsible for with them.  The problem is that handlers for these objects stick around and continue to try to manipulate the DOM after the objects have been destroyed.

Below is the code that I have that seems to work.  However I do not care for the way the handlers are destroyed and I suspect it may not be good for jQuery.  Is there a better way?

```
        var ID: "uniqueID",
    connectEvents: function ()
    {
      $(someDiv).on("customEvent", this, this.eventHandler);
    },
    eventHandler: function (e)
    {
        //do some stuff to the DOM
    },
    destroy: function ()
    {
      var gridCell = this;
      if (jQuery(someDiv).data("events"))
      {
         var handlers = jQuery(someDiv).data("events").customEvent
         var handlerIndex = -1;
         $(handlers).each(function (i, handler)
         {
            if (handler.data.ID === ID)
               handlerIndex = i;
         });
         if (handlerIndex > 0)
         {
            handlers.splice(handlerIndex, 1);
         }
      }
      //Destroy some Dom elements
    }
```

Comment: can namespace the events and use `off('customEvent.namespace`)`

Comment: If you use `$(elem).remove()` to remove an element from the DOM, then all jQuery event handlers and all regular DOM event handlers are automatically cleaned up for you.  I don't understand why you would have a problem with this.  Perhaps you can illustrate the problem you are actually having and show us the code that removes items from the DOM.  You are not supposed to have to clean up event handlers when elements are removed from the DOM if you remove them correctly.  So, the problem is probably upstream from where you're trying to fix things.

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl that is what I needed.  I did not understand event namespaces, but now it works fine.
To set up the handler I use: 
$(someDiv).on("customEvent." + this.ID, this, this.eventHandler);
To disconnect:
$(someDiv).off("customEvent." +this.ID, this.eventHandler);

Answer (score 0):

lets say the elements have a similar class 'test',

What you could do is:

```
$('.test').click(function(){
   $(this).off(); // remove all event handlers assigned to this object with class test that has been clicked.

   $(this).remove(); // removes the element
})
```

Comment: make sure to remove the event handler first and then remove the element  that used to have the handler

Comment: The idea is that I do not want to remove the event handlers from the objects that have not been destroyed.  Those event handlers need to remain active.  "off" kills everything.

Answer (score 0):

Event handling is delegated to an ancestor div with the statement :

```
$(someDiv).on("customEvent", this, this.eventHandler);
```

If this is the only statement that attaches `this.eventHandler`, and if you still see `eventHandler` behaviour after a target element has been removed, then `somediv` **must** still contain some other element, which also delegates its "customEvent" to the ancestor div.

Event namespacing as per @charlietfl 's suggestion may well fix the immediate problem but I don't think it's a full solution. Something more fundamental needs to be fixed.

You are probably delegating "customEvent" to more elements than you realise.

Comment: This is what is happening, and it is desired behavior. Sorry, I wasn't clear before, but someDiv never gets removed.  The divs that get removed are children of someDiv